# Output nested tags with one single ViewHelper

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers

I have a TYPO3 project with an extension using Extbase and to implement lazy loading and retina images while maintaining compatibility if javascript is disabled, I need to generate some output like this:

```
<noscript data-src-small="small.jpg" data-src-large="large.jpg" data-width="300" data-height="200">
  <img src="small.jpg" width="300" height="200">
</noscript>
```

So I wrote a custom ViewHelper (or rather I copied and modified an existing one) that does exactly this and it works, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right, because I'm manually creating the `<img>` like this:

```
$content = '<img class="'.$class.'" alt=" " src="'.$imageSource.'" width="'.$imageInfo[0].'" height="'.$imageInfo[1].'">';
$this->tag->setContent($content);
```

I wonder if there isn't a better way to do this, ideally I'd like to call the standard `ImageViewHelper::render()` function inside my custom ViewHelper.

Is there any way to do that? Should that even be done at all?

I am aware, I could adjust my template like this:

```
<x:noscript src="filename.jpg" width="300">
  <f:image src="filename.jpg" width="300" />
</x:noscript>
```

(`x:noscript`is supposed to be my custom ViewHelper)
and call `renderChildren()` inside my ViewHelper.

But then I would have to repeat `src="filename.jpg" width="300"` and I generally don't like to repeat input if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use a partial. It would look like this:

```
{namespace x=Yourcompany\Yourproduct\ViewHelpers}
<f:comment>
    Parameters:
     * src:     src of the image
     * width:   Width of the image
</f:comment>

<x:noscript src="{src}" width="{width}">
    <f:image src="{src}" width="{width}" />
</x:noscript>
```

You can use it like this:

```
<f:render
    partial="Path/To/Partial"
    arguments="{width: 300, src: 'filename.jpg'}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks. That means I should in fact not write a ViewHelper that generates nested output? Additionally, at the moment I call my ViewHelper inside a partial, is it possible (and advisable) to call a partial from inside a partial?

Comment: Yes, you can safely call partials from within partials - I'd recommend it, so the template parts don't get too big and managable. Same as when splitting a program into smaller pieces (if you have programming experience).